# Nested resources route for projects/tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I have projects and events, each project can have events and events can be without a project. Its possible to access /projects/:id/events and /events.

Which route is requiered to access /projects/events and how can i access this information in events_controller?

```
# current routes.rb
resources :projects do
    resources :events
end
resources :events
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use namespace to do this

```
namespace :projects do
  resources :events
end
```